# AngularJS Calculate Random Value Only Once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, I made a filter to show one number as the sum of two random numbers.

```
 myApp.filter('toSum', function() {
  return function(text) {
    var number = parseInt(text);
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * number);
    var y = number - x;
    return x + ' + ' + y;
  };
});
```

Unfortunately, because of the random variable - the values of "x + y" appear to get updated again and again in the browser - as fast as the code can run.

Am I using filters for the wrong thing?  How should I make Angular not re-run/refresh code with that has random numbers involved?

Comment: Of course it'll re-render again and again and again, the value keeps changing and thus it keeps being 'dirty' :)

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the problem.  How do I fix it? (I realize this is a noob question)

Comment: Ohh I figured it out, just sleepy, I'll leave this question up though - someone else will have the same problem eventually

Comment: If you figured it out, post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter('toSum', function() {
                        var Random = (function() {
                            var x = Math.random();
                                function get() {
                                    return x;
                                }
                                return get;
                        })();
                        return function(text) {
                            var z = Random();
                            var number = parseInt(text);
                            var x = Math.floor(z * number);
                            var y = number - x;
                            return x + ' + ' + y;
                        };
                    })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 0):

So, I remembered that functions bound to the Angular $scope get updated/refreshed, but variables do not.

I created a variable inside my controller to hold the string "x + y" - and I update that value when the sum of x + y is set (this happens just once).